# ReportExecutionService fetches old data

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I have a report (.rdl) file stored in sql server 2005 server. This report will pull out data from database and render them. I have a button on my web application, which will use ReportExecutionService rending the report and send it to printer. Everything seems to work just fine. Until I find out that the report rendered through ReportExecutionService is pulling old data from database. I open my application and add some data to database. When I run the report on sql server it is pulling out the newly entered data. However when I print the report from web application it is pulling old data. My newly entered data is missing. After a long period of idle time when I print the report again it's pulling out the correct data. I feel like it's using a cached copy of the report. However I can't find any material supporting my theory. Anyone has better idea? Thanks.